# SQL compound unique key with null

Tags: mysql, sql, hsqldb, nullable, unique-key

This is how I create the table:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS division (
DIV_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,
DIV_CODE VARCHAR(10) ,
DIV_NAME VARCHAR(20) ,
GR_ID INTEGER ,
UNIQUE (DIV_CODE, DIV_NAME, GR_ID) ,
CONSTRAINT FK1 FOREIGN KEY (GR_ID) REFERENCES grade(GR_ID) )
```

If a row exists where `DIV_CODE="1"`, `DIV_NAME="1"` and `GR_ID=1`, and I try inserting another row with values "1", "1" and 1, then I get a SQL integrity error, which is expected.

If a row exists where `DIV_CODE="1"`, `DIV_NAME="1"` and `GR_ID=null`, and I try inserting another row with vales "1", "1" and null, then the new row is inserted. I now have 2 rows with the same values for each column. Can I setup the table differently to get a similar integrity error for this scenario?

Thanks

EDIT
removed `NOT NULL` from `GR_ID` definition.

Comment: Consider always naming your constraints. It can be painful in some upgrade scenarios if you use the server supplied names.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Different vendors behave differently

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is in HSQLDB.

Comment: @StingyJack 2 years later I see the wisdom in your comment :)

Comment: 5yrs later...different project, different table, same problem, any takers? @a_horse_with_no_name I'm now on mySQL.

Comment: Make up your mind, please tag appropriately, which DBMS? Also please do not add EDITs, just edit. Also please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56093677/3404097 + UNIQUE. https://stackoverflow.com/q/42064759/3404097.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do unique constraint works with NULL value in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064759/how-to-do-unique-constraint-works-with-null-value-in-mysql)

Comment: Please reaserch before considering posting a question & reflect your research. "A generated column can be part of a foreign key or unique constraints or a column of an index. This capability is the main reason for using generated columns. A generated column may contain a formula that computes a value based on the values of other columns. Fast searches of the computed value can be performed when an index is declared on the generated column. Or the computed values can be declared to be unique, using a UNIQUE constraint on the table."