# Set a unique constraint only when a field is null

Tags: mysql, constraints, unique-constraint, mysql-5.6

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `executed_tests` (
    `id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    `user_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `test_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `start_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `completed_date` DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I want to set up an unique constraint on fields `user_id` and `test_id`, but only when `conclusion_date` is null. If `conclusion_date` is not null, the constraint doesn't apply.

So there will exist only one incomplete execution per user and test.

Something like this:

```
UNIQUE(`user_id`, `test_id`) WHEN (`completed_date` IS NULL)
```

How can I accomplish this on MySQL 5.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL supports [functional key parts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts) since **8.0.13**.

- If your version is sufficiently recent you can define your index as:

  ```
  UNIQUE(`user_id`, `test_id`, (IFNULL(`completed_date`, -1)))
  ```

  ([Demo on dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=658e845559da6f793ec56b4ade25c01f))

  Note that the above index will also prevent duplciate dates for completed executions. If those should be valid then a slightly modified index would work:

  ```
  UNIQUE(`user_id`, `test_id`, (
      CASE WHEN `completed_date` IS NOT NULL
      THEN NULL
      ELSE 0
  END))
  ```

  ([Demo on dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ccf642b98fa4a32b6c4cf6ca62e83e9b))

  Although then it starts to feel a bit dirty ;)
- If you have at least version **5.7** you can use a (virtual) [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) as workaround:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE `executed_tests` (
      `id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
      `user_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
      `test_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
      `start_date` DATE NOT NULL,
      `completed_date` DATE,
      `_helper` CHAR(11) AS (IFNULL(`completed_date`, -1)),
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE(`user_id`, `test_id`, `_helper`)
  );
  ```

  ([Demo on dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=54859dc26816c4042b517cf7e8012f5e))
- If you are stuck on **5.6** then a combination of a regular (non-virtual) column and slightly modified `INSERT` statements would work:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE `executed_tests` (
      `id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
      `user_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
      `test_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
      `start_date` DATE NOT NULL,
      `completed_date` DATE,
      `is_open` BOOLEAN,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE(`user_id`, `test_id`, `is_open`)
  );
  ```

  In this case you would set `is_open` to `true` for incomplete executions and to `NULL` after completion, making use of the fact that two `NULL`s are treated as not equal.

  ([Demo on dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=98dd1efcf1ee972ad6349ff52dcf89c0))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in this project I'm limited to version 5.6.

Comment: If non-virtual columns (i.e. different INSERTs) would work then my update might help.